# Wrong dilations in Conv2DBackpropFilter during backpropagation in Tensorflow C++

Tags: c++, windows, tensorflow, machine-learning

When calling the session.run for the back propagation I'm getting the following error:

```
"Executor failed to create kernel. Invalid argument: Current implementation does not yet support dilations in the batch and depth dimensions.
         [[Node: Conv2DBackpropFilter = Conv2DBackpropFilter[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", dilations=[1443866016, 391, 4, 0], padding="SAME", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_Placeholder_0_0, Shape_13, ReluGrad)]]"
```

The dilations variable of my Conv2D layer seems to be getting an absurd value. But when calling the forward propagation it runs without error. (the dilation sizes seem to change every run as well)

I build up the Conv2D layer like this:

```
//Describe weights and biases for convLayer1
int filterH = 3;
int filterW = 3;
int filterIn = 3;
int filterOut = 1;
auto w1 = Variable(root, filterShape, DT_FLOAT);
auto b1 = Variable(root, { filterOut }, DT_FLOAT);

auto assignW1 = Assign(root, w1, RandomUniform(root, { filterH, filterW, filterIn, filterOut }, DT_FLOAT));
auto assignB1 = Assign(root, b1, RandomUniform(root, { filterOut }, DT_FLOAT));
TF_CHECK_OK(root.status());

auto convLayer1 = Conv2D(root, inputPlaceholderX, w1, stridesShape, "SAME"); //SAME = 0 padding to fit
TF_CHECK_OK(root.status());

//Add bias
auto convBias1 = BiasAdd(root, convLayer1, b1);
TF_CHECK_OK(root.status());

//Next layers...
```

Then I add L2 regularization and apply the gradient descent to the weights and bias:

```
vector<Output> regs;
regs.push_back(L2Loss(root, w1));
regs.push_back(L2Loss(root, w2));

auto regularization = AddN(root, regs);
TF_CHECK_OK(root.status());

auto cost = ReduceMean(root, Square(root, Sub(root, softmaxLayer, labelsY)), { 0,1 });
auto loss = Add(root, cost, Mul(root, Cast(root, 0.01, DT_FLOAT), regularization));
TF_CHECK_OK(root.status());

//Add gradients operations
std::vector<Output> gradientOutputs;
TF_CHECK_OK(AddSymbolicGradients(root, { loss }, { w1, b1, w2, b2 }, &gradientOutputs));

//update the weights and bias using gradient descent
auto applyW1 = ApplyGradientDescent(root, w1, Cast(root, 0.01, DT_FLOAT), { gradientOutputs[0] });
auto applyB1 = ApplyGradientDescent(root, b1, Cast(root, 0.01, DT_FLOAT), { gradientOutputs[1] });
auto applyW2 = ApplyGradientDescent(root, w2, Cast(root, 0.01, DT_FLOAT), { gradientOutputs[2] });
auto applyB2 = ApplyGradientDescent(root, b2, Cast(root, 0.01, DT_FLOAT), { gradientOutputs[3] });
TF_CHECK_OK(root.status());

ClientSession session(root);

//Initialize the weights and biases by running the assign nodes once
TF_CHECK_OK(session.Run({ assignW1, assignB1, assignW2, assignB2 }, nullptr));
```

Finally in the training loop I call forward propagation with:

```
TF_CHECK_OK(session.Run({ { inputPlaceholderX, imagesInput }, { labelsY, labelsInput } }, { loss }, &outputs));
```

And backwards with:

```
TF_CHECK_OK(session.Run({ { inputPlaceholderX, imagesInput },{ labelsY, labelsInput } }, { applyW1, applyB1, applyW2, applyB2, softmaxLayer }, nullptr));
```

The forward run executes without issues, but the back seems to call with a random filter size. When I remove applyW1 from the Run call it seems to run fine. Any ideas?